# How to launch emulator on jenkins and run test scripts through appium on it

Tags: android, jenkins, appium, appium-android

I have setup the Jenkins and I'm using android emulator plugin to launch the emulator.
I have configured maven project and I have started appium server via script itself.

**Issue:**
Whenever I run the build on Jenkins, emulator launch successfully and appium server started but it gives me the error" zero devices connected"
But when I run adb device on the console it is showing me the attached device.

Comment: What plug-in launches an emulator?  Does it wait for the emulator to fully load and finish booting before returning to your code?  I launch an emulator through my code and wait for the various boot stages to complete before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using android emulator plugin.
Yes it is wait untill the boot process gets completed.
I didn't launch the emulator through my code can you please suggest if this is the good aproach.